# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Quantum Computing has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: glS]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6219979578933248).

Comment: Congratulations, @gIS! :-)

Comment: Hey, congrats @glS! I haven't been around for a while, but it's great seeing the site is still running well and is in good hands. I might hang around more in the coming future.

Comment: thanks! good to hear